# How to convert a web page(html,css,js) into android app

Tags: android

I want to make an app for android 4.4 that loads and runs a web page offline. I want to play this modified 2048 game (http://sanchit18.github.io ) on nexus-5 device as an app. How to do that using eclipse adt or android studio?

Also, the webpage displays the graphics correctly, but the images in the tiles render incorrectly when run on a mobile device in web browser. How to correct this? Please help with these two queries.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the webpage in a [PhoneGap WebView](http://phonegap.com/)?

Comment: No need to write native code, just put all resources in `.rar` file and upload it to [here](https://build.phonegap.com/)

Comment: Adobe PhoneGap Build Service worked well... Thanks. It easily created an apk file from the git link. However, while installing it the app requested dozens of permissions that are not at all required for the intended functionality. Is it a default for this service to request all the general permissions while converting to apk? Is there a way to remove all the requested permissions?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). [WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) allows you to display web pages as a part of your activity layout.

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is probably the most efficient way to convert a web page into an app. It is open source and generates apps for every platform, not just Android.

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose I used Phonegap a lot, and in the past I would have recommended it.

Unfornutaley Phonegap has an important disadvantage: whenever a security update of Phonegap is released, Google Play requires you to upgrade your app. If you have written many apps (like I did), having to recreate all of them (3 times in latest 2 years) is quite annoying. Therefore I would recommend Webview instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use App Builder to convert html to android app. App Builder can be easily downloaded at google playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Use a web view

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

And there is a tutorial here

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Intel XDK software. Tha following steps can make you to create apps.

1. Install Indel XDK from https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk
2. Import your html files in it.
3. Convert as App(Android, Ios, Windows)

Comment: it says that it has been discontinued, is there any other xdk ?

Answer (score -3):

**To convert your website into android app please visit this link**

**Paid version:**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.web2apkbuilder.app.paid

**Free Version:**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.web2apkbuilder.app.free

***The generated apk will support from Kitkat to Latest Android Version.***