# How can I convert my responsive website easily into native iOS and Android application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, yes... How can I convert my responsive website easily into native iOS and Android application? It is written in HTML5, CSS3, PHP, JavaScript (jQuery) and uses mySQL database. I want it to become a native mobile application that I can sell via app/play store. How can I convert it?

No, the provided solution (duplicate question) does not help because I am using php and mysql. And I need it both for iOS and for Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a web page(html,css,js) into android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106709/how-to-convert-a-web-pagehtml-css-js-into-android-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of converting your javascript codes into native codes(obj C, java). You can just create a iOS & Android native  projects with a webview & load your HTML app into it.

By doing this, you have an advantage like: when you do any enhancements or bug fixes in html code - no need to submit updated builds to AppStore/play store (because you have hosted the HTML pages into web view)

Refer this for more details: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_hybrid_webviews_index.md.html

Comment: Can it convert the php code? And isn't it only for Android?

Comment: It's not about converting your code. You will host the html/php/asp pages in webserver. And then call hosted webpage's URL in native webview

Comment: And will I be able to sell it via app/play store?

Comment: Yes. You can sell in both stores

Comment: Glad I clarified you

Comment: **To convert your website into android app please visit this link**

**Paid version:**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.web2apkbuilder.app.paid

**Free Version:**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.web2apkbuilder.app.free

***The generated apk will support from Kitkat to Latest Android Version.***

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cordova and Phonegap for converting the same code into Mobile app for iOS and Android but this will be hybrid app not native and it will work fine, if your app is not so huge.Find the below link for simple steps of conversion.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: Well, I have created some sort of a social network. Will it work fine?